# Django Operational Error: foreign key mismatch

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I have two models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='todos')
    # TODO: Add confirmation before deleting category
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="todos_in_category", null=True) 
    item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Previously, Category's PK was the default id, however, I changed it to the name field. When I ran the migrations, i received the operational error. Thinking that it was perhaps due to a conflict between the existing id fields and the new primary key, I cleared the data in the database but with no success. Any ideas as to what could be the issue here? Thanks!

Comment: If clearing your database is an option then deleting all your migration files and recreating them would be the simplest solution. Otherwise you will have to create multiple migrations that add temporary foreign keys and migrate data

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't mind clearing the database as there's nothing sensitive in it, but as far as you can tell, there's nothing wrong otherwise?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your models, the problem is changing a models primary key. A `ForeignKey` defaults to pointing at the primary key of the related model, you can't just change the primary key of a model that has a foreign key to it without a fairly complex migration

Comment: Thanks for your help, everything is working now!